# Does The Daus's counterattack work with Trifurcated Strike?

Tags: inscryption

When The Daus card is played, it summons Chimes in the spaces next to it. If an enemy attacks a Chime, the Daus will counter attack that enemy.

If I give The Daus a multi-attack ability like Bifurcated or Trifurcated Strike, will The Daus's counterattack hit multiple spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Daus with Trifurcated Strike will only counterattack the enemy that attacked the Chime.

https://clips.twitch.tv/SneakyElatedSwanTakeNRG-IIR_znZ9OOy5262b